# Mobile emulator Selenium tests fail in Jenkins but not in cmd

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I have a test that always fail when running inside Jenkins.

My project includes Selenium webdriver, JAVA, Maven, TestNG, Jenkins, Allure (reports).
I have a few suites of tests with 100+ test cases, and I iterate them through 3 different browsers (the tests run in parallel using TestNG). They all run (using maven command line) and pass in my development laptop, and on the test server when using a command line.

I have 2 problems regarding Jenkins and separated them into 2 questions- one of them is described in this question, and the other (IE11 issue) is here.

The problem starts when running inside Jenkins in the test server! 
The test fail in mobile emulator (Chrome browser) - in the test I click on a link to verify that a new window was opened with the correct url.
I tried 3 types of clicks (Selenium click, Actions, JS) and all returned a null handle.

**The code:**

Here I create the main window handle and click the link:

```
String mwh = driver.getWindowHandle();
WebElement poweredBy = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Consts.POWERED_BY_XPATH_1000))));
poweredBy.click();
```

And this is, part of, the method that gets the handle and verify the new window:

```
public boolean closePopupWindow(String mwh, String mTitle, String layoutNumber) {
// For IE11- make sure popup blocker is turned off in the options. else it will have only one window handle and fail
boolean isOpenedWindowCorrect = false; 
String newWindow = null;
Set<String> handlers = driver.getWindowHandles();

for (String window : handlers) {
  if (!window.equals(mwh)) {
    newWindow = window;
  }
}
// the focus is on the main page. need to switchTo new page and close it
driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
System.out.println("The focus now is on the NEW window");
String newTitle = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(newTitle);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: handle=null
>       at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:34)
>       at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:42)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap.of(ImmutableBiMap.java:73)
>       at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(ImmutableMap.java:123)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:995)
>       at il.carambola.pages.Page.closePopupWindow(Page.java:786)

Do you think there is a security issue that Jenkins wont open new windows in the browser? Is it VERY slow to open the window?
The same tests PASS when not using mobile emulator. (I have the same test in Chrome and Firefox and it succeed to click and pass the verification).

JDK 1.8.0_162

Jenkins V 2.121.1

Server- AWS t2.large - 8GB RAM, Windows server 2016 Data center, 64bit

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that when your program gets to this line

```
driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
```

that `newWindow` is still null. The way this is written, it could be a timing issue, and it could be another issue causing the popup to not show up. To make sure it's not a timing issue, I would suggest adding some kind of wait for there to be multiple window handles before you try to switch windows. Something like

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(d -> d.getWindowHandles().size() == 2);
```

If that wait fails, then you know the popup is being blocked and can go from there.

Comment: Thanks Micah, I'll try it in a sec (even though I did gave it Thread.sleep(4000) before entering the closePopupWindow().  Its not in my example above ) . I understand that the arrow "->" is a Lambda expression. will it work outside IntelliJ?

Comment: Hey again, it didn't worked :( This is the error I'm getting: _Expected condition failed: waiting for il.carambola.pages.Page$$Lambda$245/942575179@7d32efcd (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
System info: host: 'EC2xxxx', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.x', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver...._

Comment: Does this pass locally (not in Jenkins) in the mobile emulator?

Comment: Yes, but it also pass w/out it :)